# merge two datagridview cells from different data type

Tags: c#

Is it possible to merge two datagridview cells, one contained string and the otherone Byte to be one string ?
the reason I'm asking is because I got two columns filled with text and images and I would like the titles of the text column to be just text no images. any idea on how to do this ? appreciated

thanks
dan

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the two columns which to be merge and make a new TemplateColumn which is the output for merging two columns. On itemDtaBound you manipulate the data of two columns and then add it into TemplateColumn